# What does 'including but not limited to' and 'to post calls' mean in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does **including but not limited** to mean here? And what means **to post calls** for artists?

> This space collects any kinds of open-call opportunities for artists
>   and arts professionals, **including but not limited to** residency
>   programs, workshops, exhibition/ festival projects. Please feel free
>   to post calls.

Comment: The list is not [**exhaustive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhaustive). *"The list is by no means exhaustive but it does capture some of the main elements."*

Comment: A "residency program" is what it says when you look that term up.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer it. It means that beyond the items mentioned other ones may also be included in the "open-call opportunities. Another example: you'll have to pay for all your expenses, including but not limited to, transportation, alimentation and accommodation.

Comment: What does 'Please feel free to post calls' means for artists who are members of this group?